# What mobile wallet software is available for BlackBerry?

Tags: wallet, mobile

Is there a technical reason why there is no mobile wallet software for BlackBerry users?

Is it just because the marketplace on BlackBerry is awkward? Or are there other technical problems?

Are the Android and iPhone markets easier (less strict) to upload apps to?

Comment: I'd guess most wallet software developers first create it for their own phones, and they probably don't use BlackBerry...

Comment: Bitcoin is a currency of the future, Blackberry is a mobile OS of the past... unlikely they'll ever meet. And if they *do* meet, it won't be very nice (fewer and fewer people will be using Blackberry, so an eventual app won't have many users, with everything this implies).

Comment: @Lohoris On what exactly do you base those claims? BlackBerry phones have been gaining a higher share of the market in the last few years in the UK.

Comment: @SeanChapman: just look with your eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand (not being a BlackBerry or Android developer, just a small iPhone one), programming for BlackBerry is more tedious and low level than programming for an iPhone or Android. The SDK is less user-friendly, and one has to develop for a lot of screen resolutions (similar to Android, not really so for the iPhone).

All in all, if someone wanted to create an app like that for BlackBerry, there shouldn't be anything stopping them, just that for now there doesn't seem to be anyone wanting to do so. Then again, since there is more and more emphasis on webapps for any smartphone, maybe the need for BlackBerry-specific app is not that urgent.

Answer (score 1):

The Blackberry World (app store) shows two wallet apps:

- [Bitcoin Wallet by Andreas Schildbach](https://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/23952882/)
- [Bitcoin Spinner](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/20080938/) (unofficial release, so I'ld check first on the Bitcoin Spinner forum thread to see if it is verified as a straight port with no wallet stealing code injected)]

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [Puut Wallet App](https://www.puutwallet.com/) for my Blackberry device for more than a year. It is easy to use for transactions & payments